# Not sure about an exercise of probability (POISSON)

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I was given this exercise:
[image]

I did this:

I know that:

> Fabric rolls of 10 meters² and according to POISSON 2 defects are
> expected for every 20 meters². Having 2 defects every 20 square meters
> means that on average there is 1 fault every 10 square meters.

A roll is of poor quality if it has 3 or more flaws.
Therefore, the probability that the roll is of poor quality:

```
P(x >= 3) = 1 – P(x < 3)
              = 1 – P(x = 0) + P(x = 1) + P(x = 2)
          = 1 – e^(-1) – [(e^(-1).1)/(1)] - [(e^(-1).2)/(2!)]
          = 1 – e^(-1).(1 + 1 + ½)
          = 0.08025
```

Let ‘n’ be the variable that shows the number of rolls reviewed, of which 4 were found to be defective:

```
n * 0.08025 = 4.
n = (4 / 0.08025) = 49.84 and this is approximately 50 rolls.
```

What should i do from now to determine the acumulated amount of money?

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks for replying. What do you mean? How would you do it?

Comment: If I understand the question, the only possible payoffs are $60, $70, and $80.

Comment: My mistake, the exponent is correct.  It's $10 m^2$ per roll, so the average is $1$ per *roll*.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the earnings, then by definition of expected value,

$$\begin{split}\mathbb E(X)&=60 \mathbb P(X=60)+70\mathbb P(X=70) +80\mathbb P(X=80)\end{split}$$

Let $p=.0803$, the chance that there are $3$ or more defects on the roll.

- The inspector earns $\$60$ if he inspects 4, 5, or 6 total rolls,
  given by probability $p^4+4p^4(1-p)+{5\choose 2}p^4(1-p)^2$.
- The inspector earns \$70 if there are 7 rolls inspected, ${6 \choose
     3}p^4(1-p)^3$.
- The inspector earns \$80 if he inspects more than 7 rolls.

So the expected earnings is $$60\left(p^4+4p^4(1-p)+{5\choose 2}p^4(1-p)^2\right) + 70\left({6 \choose
   3}p^4(1-p)^3\right) + 80\left(1-\left(p^4+4p^4(1-p)+{5\choose 2}p^4(1-p)^2)+{6 \choose
   3}p^4(1-p)^3\right)\right)=79.94757$$

```
p=.0803
60*(p^4+4*p^3*(1-p)+choose(5, 2)*p^4*(1-p)^2) + 70*choose(6, 3)*p^4*(1-p)^3+80*(1-(p^4+4*p^3*(1-p)+choose(5, 2)*p^4*(1-p)^2+choose(6, 3)*p^4*(1-p)^3))
79.94757
```

Comment: Hey Stacker. Thanks for replying.
Can i ask you something? Is my reasoning correct? Are my calculations good too?

Comment: Your calculation of `P(X>=3)` is good but then `n` is a random variable, so the reasoning is slightly off

Comment: So, my .0803 should be okay, right? I was a little worried about that value

Comment: That's because a guy from above said that i you have used -0.1 instead of -1 :/

Comment: The value is correct, because it is a poisson process the defects will be $\text{Poisson}(1)$ and probability of 3 or more defects is $1-.3679-.3679-.1839=.0803$.

Comment: Stacker, did you miss the 80 in the first sentence? i mean 80P(x = 80)

Comment: Stacker, just one question: how did you get this probability: (p^4+4*p^3*(1-p)+choose(5, 2)*p^4*(1-p)^2)

Comment: It comes from negative binomial distribution, e.g. $p^4$ is you get 4 defects in a row, $4p^3(1-p)$ is the fifth is a defect, then in the first four, one of them is non-defective, and ${5\choose 2}p^4(1-p)^2$ is that the 6th is a defective, and then in the first 5 there is 2 non-defectives.